# Customise thunderbird 78 looks

Tags: thunderbird

Gday gents.

I've got a thunderbird 78.7.1 (64bit) install here on win10.
Trying to change the looks a bit, because even though I like the light interface, the header row in the list is indiscernible from the rest.

However, it seems that all the themes are incompatible with this version, in fact most mods are.

I've looked at trying to use the userchrome.css method mentioned somewhere, but only god knows what the styles are, and firebug is also incompatible so I've no idea how to find the classes/ids of the elements in play.

Anyone can recommend any way out of this? (apart from switching email clients - I can figure that one out myself)

Many thanks

Edit: can the over-zealous editors please stop editing my post?  I'm quite happy with it as it is, it contains niceties which you guys regularly remove.  It's not  nice to remove niceties, and doing pointless edits.  Find something else to do, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug's been discontinued, but [Firebug lives on in Firefox DevTools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

DevTools is accessible in Thunderbird at `Tools > Developer Tools > Developer Toolbox`. If this does nothing, go into the Config Editor, set `devtools.chrome.enabled` to **true**, restart Thunderbird, and it should then work. Documentation is available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools.

As an example, I changed styling of the Subject column heading as shown below with the following CSS in `<profile_folder>/chrome/userChrome.css`:

```
#subjectCol .treecol-text {
   color:#FFFFFF;
   background-color:#FF8800;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-style:italic;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks mate!

Comment: Hm...I had a chance to look at this, and sadly I could not find out how to change the header row.   The devtools output is quite unreadable - it seems to just hide the parts where the important structural elements would be.   Is there some other config to get the whole document map to show up?

Comment: Not that I know of. To find particular elements, I generally use the 'node picker' to [select an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Select_an_element) and, if necessary, poke around in the code near what's been selected to find a particular element.

Comment: Ahha!  Thanks again - that nodepicker did the job.